# Mongodb port not opening

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine

for the last 2 days ive been working on a java application that uses mongodb i have already setup the mongodb in my instance and open the tcp 27017 on network firewall rules but when i test this port to check if its fowarded or try to connect mongodb i cant because it says "port 27017 closed".

I even tried to change from priority 1000 to 65520 but nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am trying to do the same thing.